# Как ограничить добавление товара в Modx Revolution имея тв поле остаток?

Tags: javascript, modx, minishop2

*Ограничение максимального числа ввода добавления в корзину minishop2* из tv **availability**
Чтобы расширить поле *availability* читаем: //github.com/zenwalker/modx-docs/blob/master/ru/01_Компоненты/03_mSearch2/03_Расширение/02_Пример_фильтрации_товаров.md

> В чанке категории каталога **tpl.msProducts.row2**:

```
<div class="col-md-3 ms2_product">
<img src="[[+thumb:default=`[[++assets_url]]components/minishop2/img/web/ms2_small.png`]]" width="120" height="90" /><br/>
<form method="post" class="ms2_form">
    <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a>
    <span class="flags">[[+new]] [[+popular]] [[+favorite]]</span>
    <br/>
    [[+price]] [[%ms2_frontend_currency]]
    [[+old_price]]
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></i> [[%ms2_frontend_add_to_cart]]</button>
    <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="[[+id]]">
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="options" value="[]">
</form>
<p><small>[[+introtext]]</small></p>
```

> *В TV* **[[+availability]** *указано наличие товара на складе; остаток*.

**Вопрос**: как сделать так, чтобы из каталога по кнопке добавить в корзину, добавлялись товары максимально из поля тв **availability**, а не 1000, как указано здесь: [core/components/minishop2/model/minishop2/mscarthandler.class.php](https://github.com/bezumkin/miniShop2/blob/master/core/components/minishop2/model/minishop2/mscarthandler.class.php)

Нас интересует *value*, то есть его *count*. Надо добавить правило больше или меньше ли поле **count < availability** в этом файле **[/assets/components/minishop2/js/web/default.js](https://github.com/bezumkin/miniShop2/blob/master/assets/components/minishop2/js/web/default.js)**

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" min="0" max="[[+availability]]" value="1">
```

> В кнопке мы видим **cart/add**. У кого какие идеи, как добавить на проверку наше поле availability в котором сохранён остаток?

```
miniShop2.controller = function () {
    var self = this;
    switch (self.sendData.action) {
        case 'cart/add':
            miniShop2.Cart.add();
            break;
        ..
```

Как расширить?
**+phx** не решил проблему в Value.

```
value="[[+availability:el=`[[+availability]]`:then=`[[+availability:notempty=`1`]]`:default=`0`]]"
value="[[+availability:ge=`[[+availability]]`:then=`[[+availability:replace=`[[+availability]]==0`]]`]]
```

Как вставить вместо 1000 ---> +availability ?

```
        $this->config = array_merge(array(
        'cart' => & $_SESSION['minishop2']['cart'],
        'max_count' => $this->modx->getOption('ms2_cart_max_count', null, 1000, true),
        'allow_deleted' => false,
        'allow_unpublished' => false,
    ), $config);
```

Comment: Кто сталкивался с этой проблемой, помогите, я не силён в js. Где **ms2_cart_max_count**, надо расширить проверку на валидность **count < availability** при добавлении в корзину по кнопке **cart/add**

Answer (score 0):

Need to add Events to add a product.
Example creat ajax on action and plugin: msAvailability

```
/** 
* msOnBeforeAddToCart - here getTVValue availability as $count if we not add field custom ms
* msOnBeforeChangeInCart - for set we catching $cart->get(); and $tmp[$key]['id'];
*/
switch ($modx->event->name) {
    case 'msOnBeforeAddToCart': 
    case 'msOnBeforeChangeInCart': 
}
```

The idea was suggested by Artem Petropavlovsky in solving the issue.

Comment: А почему на англ.? Перведите, пожалуйста.